# Узнать состояние клавиатуры в Lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-inputmethodmanager

Так получилось, что `InputMethodManager` не хранит в себе текущее состояние клавиатуры, под "состояние" подразумевается видна или не видна системная клава. Есть код, который работает на всех версиях кроме Lollipopa.

```
/**
     * It checks that keyboard is showing now.
     *
     * @return {@code true} if keyboard is showing, {@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean isKeyboardShown() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) solo.getCurrentActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        // Software keyboard can be opened only if InputMethodManager exists and active for current context.
        if (imm != null && imm.isActive() && isKeyboardActive) {

            // In "full screen edit mode" keyboard is shown.
            if (UIHelpers.isFullscreenEditMode())
                return true;

            // If diff between screen height and android:id/content view height more than 0 then keyboard is shown.
            if (VIEW_CONTENT_WITHOUT_KEYBOARD.isVisible() && getKeyboardHeightRelativeToAndroidContent() != 0)
                return true;

            // If opened dialog and shift more than 2px then keyboard shown. Value of 2px is permissible error of method getDialogShift().
            if (DialogHelpers.getDialogShift() > 2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

абсолютно всегда возвращает `true`

```
imm != null && imm.isActive()
```

но в lollipope еще и возвращает `true` вот это условие

```
if (VIEW_CONTENT_WITHOUT_KEYBOARD.isVisible() && 
    getKeyboardHeightRelativeToAndroidContent() != 0)
```

где

```
/**
     * Returns the height of keyboard as difference between "android:id/content" view height and bottom of used {@link
     * android.view.Window}. Returns height only if it more than {@link #MINIMUM_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT} for platform less
     * then "Marshmallow". For "Marshmallow" platform returns real height of keyboard.
     * NOTE: not working in fullscreen edit mode and for dialogs (always returns {@code 0}).
     *
     * @return Height of keyboard (in pixels).
     */
    public static int getKeyboardHeightRelativeToAndroidContent() {
        View contentView = VIEW_CONTENT_WITHOUT_KEYBOARD.assertExists();
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        contentView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
        if (isAndroidMarshmallowOrNewer()) {

            //Note: contentView.getRootView() return full height of screen with navigation bar for marshmallow platform
            //but for less platform without navigation bar.
            return ((View) contentView.getParent().getParent()).getHeight() - rect.bottom;
        } else {
            int height = contentView.getRootView().getHeight() - rect.bottom;
            return height > MINIMUM_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT ? height : 0;
        }
    }
```

Метод подсмотрен на англоязычном SO. 
Так вот вопрос: есть ли у кого какие-нибудь предложения как правильней хранить состояние клавиатуры? Булин флаг не устраивает, послкольку проект это фреймворк для тестирования приложений, и програмно клавиатура не всегда открывается/закрывается, т.е. используя свои методы `hideKeyBoard/openKeyBoard`

Comment: дак в вашем же вопросе и есть ответ, почему бы не хранить состояние в ее высоте? и почему бы не воспользоваться ViewTreeObserver? многие инструменты для автоматизированного тестирования его используют

Comment: @LexHobbit клавиатура не сдвигает контент в приложении а ViewTreeObsever никак не отслеживает ее, так же как и она не отображается в Layout Hierarhy Monitor. Кажется нашел решение через adb команду, сейчас доделываю

Comment: через dumpsys  чтоли ?

Comment: @LexHobbit Ага=) Нашел вот такую команду adb shell dumpsys window InputMethod. Которая возвращает некую информацию, через которую можно проверить видна клава или нет

Comment: я просто немного не понял, что вы в итоге хотите сделать =) а так вариантов дофига, но в каждом есть ньюансы (Василий Иванович). И под разные цели необходимо использовать разные способы =)

Comment: Просто иногда невнятно/непонятно излагаюсь, извиняюсь) В целом - не получалось понять открыта клава или нет на лолипопе. Это из-за того, что контент фрагмента никак не двигался при ее открытии. Но теперь, кажись, решение нашел